# Run a Virtual machine in Windows 7 Virtual PC at background

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

I'd like to run a windows server 2008 in Virtual PC on my windows 7 machine. It seems like I can either turn on the vm with its screen on, or turn it off/hibernate. Is it possible to make it run at the background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Virtual PC, there is no built-in way of doing this. This is what Microsoft designed [**Virtual Server**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Virtual_Server) for. VMWare can run virtual machines in the background if an alternative is a possibility for you. See [**The How-To Geek's Guide**](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/vmware/make-virtual-machines-always-hide-to-the-system-tray-in-vmware-workstation/) on how to run them in the background on VMWare. For a free solution, [**VirtualBox can run VMs in the background**](http://sebastian-bauer.ws/en/2008/11/06/windows-run-virtualbox-in-the-background.html) as well with the `-headless` switch.

Answer (score 0):

run VMware, i've been using it and in my opinion is the best :)